# Saving/Reading a file from File.applicationStorageDirectory in an iPad Flex4.5 app

Tags: actionscript-3, apache-flex, flex4.5, flex-mobile

I have a Flex application (SDK 4.5.1) which runs on iPad... I need to download any files, put them in local directory (like the File.applicationStorageDirectory) and then view the file inside my application.

So in my test application a downloaded a png image using the urlLoader class.

Here it is the complete handler of the download:

```
private function onComplete3(event:Event):void{
 try{
    var ba:ByteArray  = event.target.data as ByteArray;
    var file:File=File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("img.png");
    var pathFile:String = file.nativePath;
    var fileStream:FileStream = new FileStream();  
    fileStream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);  
    fileStream.writeBytes(ba);  
    fileStream.addEventListener(Event.CLOSE, fileClosed);  
    fileStream.addEventListener(IOErrorEvent.IO_ERROR,function(e:IOErrorEvent):void{
       status0.text = "STATE : ERROR 3"
    });
    fileStream.close();     
    status0.text = "STATO : OK";
    path0.text = pathFile; 
    immagine0.source = pathFile; 
  catch(e:Error){
    status0.text = "STATE : ERROR 2"
  }
}
```

On my iPad I can see the downloaded file exists, but when I run the line immagine0.source = pathFile (which is an image component), nothing appears... Maybe I can write a file but I cannot read it?

Comment: Can you please try reading the file into a filestream object, and converting that filestream object into bitmapdata for direct display?  Then we can see if the error is related to Security, file path issues, or data load corruption.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

After 6 hours of debug and coding...i solved this problem with a very simple solution...
changed the line

```
var pathFile:String = file.nativePath;
```

with

```
var pathFile:String = file.url;
```

He solved the file.url in this way:

```
app-storage:/img.png
```

.Now it works! Hope this post will be helpful for someone other have this problem..Thanks to all

Answer (score 0):

The following 2 functions are to write and read file in Flex 4.5.

```
protected function button1_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("samples/test.txt");
    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream()
    stream.open(file, FileMode.WRITE);
    stream.writeUTFBytes(contents.text);
    stream.close();
}
protected function button2_clickHandler(event:MouseEvent):void
{
    var file:File = File.applicationStorageDirectory.resolvePath("samples/test.txt");
    var stream:FileStream = new FileStream()
    stream.open(file, FileMode.READ);
    results.text = stream.readUTFBytes(stream.bytesAvailable);
    stream.close();
}
```